# Which icons are needed for publishing in Play Store?

Tags: android, icons

I want to publish an app in the Play Store. As I noticed, it's neccessary to upload some screenshots f.e. an app icon.
But which one I have to upload if I didn't create an own icon? Till now I'm using the launch icons that will be automatically added when creating a new Android project.
And what is the meaning of the second graphic? Should I upload a screenshot of my app UI there? I'm a bit confusing...

Comment: I have added an answer in response. Let me know if you have any other doubts...

Comment: First of all - thanks for your answer! If I have no designer for the next few weeks, is it then allowed to publish with the ic_lanucher.png (standard icon from the SDK) temporarily?

Comment: Don't publish an app with that ic_lanucher.png icon... The icon is the app's identity and hence it's very important . I'm no designer either ! Therefore, I asked my friend from the workplace to develop one for me. :) Besides, I don't know if you'll get 512x512 ic_launcher...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a designer who is an expert in photoshop, you can request them for designing the icons. These are the mandatory icons that you need in order to publish on Play Store :

**1. Screenshots**

**Maximum 8, Minimum 2 :**
What you can do is take a screenshot from a high resolution device of important screens of your app. (Power button + reduce Volume button)

**2. High resolution App icon**

Required 1, dimensions 512x512. Basically a high resolution launcher icon.

**3. Feature Graphic**

Required 1, dimensions 1024x500. This is the icon which is displayed as the backdrop image of your app.

You can refer to this for more details
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en

I'm attaching few screenshots from my app. This is how these icons will be shown on play store. Follow the sequence numbers 1,2 and 3->

[image]

[image]